# I want to clonate a repository inside a repository

Tags: github

I have to clonate a repository inside a macro repository.
I have this macro repo has subfolders with repositories.
I need to clone another project more.

- I've tried with the typical clone + add + push.

hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add  ****
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached ---
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.

- I've tried with:

git remote add upstream ***
+
git pull upstream master + add + push + commit

This cloned all the submodules but not the important files I've wanted.

- I've tried the usage of submodules.

Comment: Your question is not clearly communicated. Can you try restating, and make your question clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try using different origin name. E.g.,

```
git remote add flutter_repo_origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

and then,

```
git push --setupstream flutter_repo_origin main
```